# Question about area calculation

Tags: analysis, conic-sections, area, polar-coordinates

I would like to calculate the area of the ellipse $5x^2 + 11y^2 = 1$ using double integrals.

Now, I know the method of calculating areas using double integrals. We will double integrate $f(x,y) = 1$ and use polar coordinates but at first, we have to "turn" the ellipse into a circle, making the switch with the Jacobian determinant.

**Question**: What is the correct substitution; substitute for example $x = \sqrt{5}u$ or substitute $u = \sqrt{5}x$? ($u$ will be one of our new two coordinates) is there any difference and why?

Comment: $x = \sqrt 5 u$ and $u = \frac {1}{\sqrt  5} x$ are essentially the same substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

$$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt 5} \quad u=\frac{y}{\sqrt {11}} $$

$$5x^2+11y^2=1\implies u^2+v^2=1$$

Note that since we are dealing with an affine transformation from the original equation

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

we'll find that the area is $\pi ab$ and since

$$a=\frac1{\sqrt{5}} \quad b=\frac1{\sqrt{11}}$$

we have that $$A=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{55}}$$

Comment: And what if we used: x = u/sqrt(5) ;

Comment: @al.al. you don't get a circle

Comment: Are the two answers given different? Between you and @DougM

Comment: @al.al. I've only write down the transformation from ellipse to circle, Doug Mo solved the integral by polar coordinates

Comment: And do you get the same result?

Comment: Yes of course since $a=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}$ and $b=\frac1{\sqrt{11}}$ we have that $$A=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{55}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot man

Comment: @al.al. You are welcome!

Comment: @al.al. Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

$x = \frac {1}{\sqrt 5} rcos \theta\\
 y = \frac 1{\sqrt {11}} r\sin\theta\\ 
dy\ dx = \frac {1}{\sqrt {55}} r \ dr\ d\theta$

$\frac {1}{\sqrt {55}} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r \ dr\ d\theta$